# How do I write an IF Statement for Percentage Formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to I write an IF statement that if I divide two negative numbers, the results show a negative percentage and not a positive percentage?

> Example:
>
> (69,002)/(11,440) = 603.16%

I need for the results to show a negative percentage.

Comment: Two observations: 1) You can format negative numbers to display with parentheses, but putting numbers in parentheses in an excel formula doesn't treat it as a negative. 2) Mathematically, dividing a negative by a negative yields a positive result.  If you are using the result in subsequent calculations, be wary of potential errors.  If you are using the forced negative as a shorthand comment on something others will see, include a footnote or explanation to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness,here's an option using the `SIGN` function as well as a slightly shorter version of Raystafarian's solution.

```
=IF(SIGN(A1)=SIGN(B1),SIGN(A1),1)*A1/B1
=IF(AND(A1<0,B1<0),-1,1)*A1/B1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values for division are in E6 and F6, just use an [if](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb?CorrelationId=dd0bba17-5d7a-4def-9a54-9da53f11482c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) with an [and](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-c192b0d8-0eeb-4768-a674-f84e6df9aefb?CorrelationId=9999ab41-191c-4a1b-81c7-d59eaed254be&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to find out if they are both negative, like this:

```
=IF(AND(E6<0,F6<0),-1*E6/F6,E6/F6)
```

Comment: Thanks for you...I used your formula and it does not change the result to a negative %. It just changed the result to 6.03% instead of it showing 603.16%.  I am trying to build a template that identifies products with a negative gross margin. Some of the products have negative net sales and negative gross  margin values. When I divide the gross margin value by the net sales value and both values are negative, my results are a positive percent. I would like to be able to identify the products that have a negative gross margin %. Do you have any other suggestions for writing the formula? Thanks

Comment: The formula works, just make sure you're doing the correct references, or check the other answer.

Comment: I followed your formula,but it is still showing a positive percentage using the correct reference. Using your formula only changed the decimal place. The percentage result is still positive.

Comment: The formula shouldn't change any decimal places. The only possibility is that at least one of the numbers is being shown or treated as a regular number instead of a percentage. For instance, 603.16% = 6.0316 as the only difference between numbers and percentages is that factor of 100.